# How to concatenate multiple results into one column in oracle?

Tags: oracle

I have the following doubt
I have the following problem, below I show the table I have

```
              customers

 id name     client_type  date
 5  Fernando   5          27/04/2020
 6  paco       6          27/04/2020
 7  jose       5          27/04/2020
 8  angel      6          27/04/2020
 9  maria      6          27/04/2020
```

I have the following query

```
select client_type from customers where date = sysdate group by client_type;
```

Which returned the following result

```
type_clients
 5
 6
```

What I need is for the following result to return

```
type_clients
5,6
```

I have tried with the following

```
select listgg (client_type, ',') within group (order by client_type)
  from CUSTOMERS
 where date = sysdate
```

But I returned more results

```
type_clients
5,5,6,6,6
```

They would help me solve the problem I have, thank you very much

Comment: Did you try `Distinct`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Oracle 12C or higher, You can directly use distinct clause inside LISTAGG -

```
select listgg (distinct client_type, ',') within group (order by client_type)
  from CUSTOMERS
 where date = sysdate
```

However if you are using below 12C, You have to use below code -

```
select listgg (client_type, ',') within group (order by client_type)
  from (select distinct client_type
          from CUSTOMERS
         where date = sysdate)
```